# Android Studio: "Found item Style/AppBaseTheme more than one time"

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I am attempting to import a project into Android Studio 0.8.9 - at first I get an error saying that the gradle level in the project (.11) is not supported.  Clicked the link to fix.  Now getting the following two errors:

```
Error: Found item Style/AppBaseTheme more than one time

Error:Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugResources'.
> C:\Users\mrshickadance9\AndroidStudioProjects\testapp\res\values\styles.xml: Error: Found item Style/AppBaseTheme more than one time
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.  Fixed it.  For some reason appbasetheme was duplicated in Android Studio, but not when i open the same exact project in Eclipse.  Very weird.